# How many NBA teams have won a playoff game starting 2 or more rookies?

Tags: basketball, nba, records, postseason

After the Bucks win on Saturday, starting Thon Maker and Malcolm Brogdon, I am wondering if another team in NBA history has ever won a playoff game starting 2+ rookie players.

Comment: Properly formatted and tagged, great job as your first post!

Answer (score 2):

Complete answer:

Not counting the 2017 Bucks, 8 teams have won playoff games with at least 2 rookies starting. Here I list the team, the playoff games they won with 2 rookies starting, and the players.

1. 2013 Golden State Warriors

   - May 8 beat San Antonio Spurs

     - Harrison Barnes
     - Draymond Green
2. 2005 Chicago Bulls

   - April 24, 27 beat Washington Wizards

     - Andres Nocioni
     - Chris Duhon
3. 2003 Orlando Magic

   - April 20, 25, 27 beat Detroit Pistons

     - Drew Gooden
     - Gordan Giricek
4. 2002 Utah Jazz

   - April 2 beat Sacramento Kings

     - Andrei Kirilenko
     - Jarron Collins
5. 1999 Houston Rockets

   - May 13 beat Los Angeles Lakers

     - Cuttino Mobley
     - Michael Dickerson
6. 1998 Cleveland Cavaliers

   - April 27 beat Indiana Pacers

     - Cedric Henderson
     - Zydrunas Ilgauskas
     - Brevin Knight
7. 1990 San Antonio Spurs

   - April 26, 28, May 1 beat Denver Nuggets
   - May 10, 12, 17 beat Portland Trail Blazers

     - David Robinson
     - Sean Elliott
8. 1986 Philadelphia 76ers

   - April 20, 22, 27 beat Washington Bullets
   - April 29 beat Milwaukee Bucks

     - Terry Catledge
     - Greg Stokes

---

Source: http://bkref.com/tiny/pcSOD

I looked at teams that had multiple players for a single season, then clicked on a player to see what playoff wins they started that year, and looked for the other rookies from that team also started the game.